# How can i get UPC barcode scanner framework for ios 5 iphone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, barcode, barcode-scanner

I developing Barcode Scanner sample app in iPhone. Am using `ZBar` framework in iphone, i think it is working on ios 4 platforms URL: `http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/`.  How can i get new version of ZBar code library that which will be suitable for iOS 5 platform. Can any one please help me to find out the solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have use zbar Api for the UPC barcode scanning and its working very fine follow the below tutorial in ios 5.

http://iphonenativeapp.blogspot.in/2011/07/qr-code-readerscanner-for-iphone-app-in.html

Comment: Mr.Parag kavar. Thanks for your answer. I will look at this. Thanks.

Comment: It is working fine in iOS 5, Xcode 4.2. I have one more clarification, how can i search the product by typing the barcode? Can you please clarify me. Thanks.

Comment: its for the read the barcode code of the product. u have to use a upc barcode database for the detail of the product.

Comment: Mr.Parag kavar. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Mr.Parag kavar. Thanks. Not yet get the database. I have asked the question regarding this. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9256700/640733 Please look at this and help me on this. Thanks. I hope on your answer. Thanks.