# Suitable api to get product details from scanned barcode iphone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, product, barcode-scanner

Am developing sample barcode scanner app. I using ZBar API to scan the barcode from the product. It is working very fine. Now, looking to get the product of the scanned barcode. I want to get the below details of the product from the api,

```
Product Name
Product Price
Selling fees (eBay or Amazon fees)
Shipping costs
Shipping dimensions
Shipping weights
```

I am searched and continuing to get the exact result for the question in google. But, not yet get it right now. Can anyone please suggest your ideas on this? Can you please suggest Amazon API to get product details by using the barcode? Thanks in advance.

**EDITED:**

I have tried this API to get the details of the product, `http://searchupc.com/` API. It returns only the Product name, price, product url, currency, storename. But, i want to show above (In question) details to the user. Please help me to find the exact API for the product details.

Comment: @ Yuvaraj.M can you please help me on how to get the product details once i get the barcode. What is the solution you found for your question

Comment: @Yuvaraj, as you mention in EDITED part of your question that http://searchupc.com/ API gives some certain details about the product and for calling that API we need UPC/EAN code but I'm not getting required UPC/EAN code, I'm just getting one stringValue that just contains some number or sometimes URL address. Can you please guide me towards getting UPC/EAN code? I'm using AVFoundation to scan bar/QR code in iOS7

Comment: @Yuvaraj.M i too need the same as Suryakant mentioned, That how you get the Product name, price, product url, currency, storename using searchupc.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends greatly on the data that's encoded in the barcode you're scanning. If you're generating the barcodes yourself then you can generate unique ids for whatever product you're barcoding. Otherwise, there's no central repository for IDs that barcodes code for, you need to determine what is being scanned (or have the user tell you) and use an appropriate API (if it exists) to look up data based on the coded ID.

Comment: Mr.Nick thanks for your answer. Am getting a barcode by barcode scanner using ZBar API, Eg: 9780764576102. How can i find the product name, price, selling fee and etc, etc. Which API i need to use to get these details. If you don't mind can you please suggest your ideas on this?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I have used this blog to scan the barcode from the product, http://iphonenativeapp.blogspot.in/2011/07/qr-code-readerscanner-for-iphone-app-in.html. Here only i have downloaded the sample code for generate/scan the barcode of the product.

Answer (score 4):

A free API is available, it's documentation can be seen here

- http://searchupc.com/api/

For using this API, u need to make a developer account

- http://searchupc.com/developers/

Comment: Is it just US products they have data on?