# Product detail using Barcode

Tags: ios, barcode, product

Hi am creating a barcode reader application , am able to get barcode number but need advice on where to lookup for product details like price , product name etc ...

Comment: [You should search for similar questions before posting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256700/suitable-api-to-get-product-details-from-scanned-barcode-iphone-app).

Comment: Hi i did search for similar question but was not able to find the answer . Wat i need is this ->appropriate API (if it exists) to look up data based on the coded ID...so that if it exist i can get the xml from it and parse the results n display in my application

Answer (score 0):

Google's Shopping Search API (see https://developers.google.com/shopping-search/) is one of many services that has a simple barcode-to-product-metadata interface and will give you back product data in XML/JSON or other. It's pretty straightforward to use, but if you're unsure of how to make it work, I believe you can look at how the barcode scanning app Zxing uses it (the code for which is available).